# rotate the gnuplot raxis label to 45 degrees without rtics

Tags: gnuplot

I have a polar plot in Gnuplot given by

```
set polar
set angles degrees
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset raxis
set ttics 0,30
set grid polar linestyle 1 dashtype 2 linecolor rgb 'grey'
set samples 200, 200
unset border

set xrange [-0.51:0.51]
set yrange [-0.51:0.51]
set size square
unset key

plot sin(2*t)*cos(2*t)
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: Polar plot]

However,

1. I want the rlabels (0, 0.1, 0.2, etc) at an angle of 45 degrees instead of them being placed on the x-axis, and
2. There should be no rtics

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just for my understanding... do you want each rtic label rotated by 45 degrees or do you want the labels (unrotated) arranged along a line rotated by 45 degrees?

Comment: @theozh labels (unrotated) should be arranged along a line rotated by 45 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the `rtics` do `set rtics scale 0`.

You can set the starting angle for polar graph (check `help theta`), however, only to `{right|top|left|bottom}` and not to 45°, but this still wouldn't help you here.
So, probably you have to set the labels "manually". Maybe there is an automatic way which I am not aware of. Check the following example.

**Code:**

```
### set rtics on 45° "axis"
reset session

set polar
set angles degrees
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset raxis
set ttics 0,30
set grid polar linestyle 1 dashtype 2 linecolor rgb 'grey'
set samples 200, 200
unset border

set xrange [-0.51:0.51]
set yrange [-0.51:0.51]
set size square
unset key
set rtics scale 0
set format r ""

myRTics = "0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5"
do for [i=1:words(myRTics)] {
    r = word(myRTics,i)
    set label i sprintf("%s",r) at r*cos(45),r*sin(45) center
}
plot sin(2*t)*cos(2*t)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Changing `theta` wouldn't help, since I still want `theta = 0` to start from the x-axis. The above code certainly does the job. But I was hoping for a more automatic Gnuplot inbuilt method. Something like `set rlabel at angle 45`. I will accept your answer after two days unless someone comes up with a slightly better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to @theozh's excellent answer, I realized I can generate the labels on the fly, by providing the start, end, and increment of the labels. So instead of

```
myRTics = "0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5"
do for [i=1:words(myRTics)] {
    r = word(myRTics,i)
    set label i sprintf("%s",r) at r*cos(45),r*sin(45) center
}
```

I will write

```
rangle = 45
rstart = 0.1 ; rend = 0.5 ; rinc = 0.1 ;
n = floor((rend-rstart)/rinc) + 1

do for [i=1:n] {
    r = rstart + (i-1)*rinc
    set label i sprintf("%g",r) at r*cos(rangle),r*sin(rangle) center
}
```

The rest of it will be as already answered by @theozh. The output doesn't change.

I am a bit surprised that Gnuplot doesn't have any inbuilt method to handle this.